# Generate dynamic precompiled filter predicates in Scala

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, code-generation

I'm looking to precompile a filter predicate to use over a large collection of data. Specifically, I will be dynamically decoding a protobuf object by the user provided String classname and allowing users to generate a predicate based on a String path into the underlying object. Ex "foo.bar.baz == 2" might compile to a bit of code like

```scala
class Filter {
  def test(in: Array[Byte]) = {
    Foo.parseFrom(in).getBar.baz == 2
  }
}
```

There seem to be several options in Scala for precompiling code. You can use macros, you can use Scalameta, there seems to be talks of a new Dotty compiler for scala3, you could also use some Java just in time compilers. My question is, what is the most future-proof method of codegen filter predicates in Scala? We currently use 2.12. I don't want to write complex filter generation code that is going to be phased out in newer versions of Scala.

Comment: macros may go away in [scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/04/19/scala-3.html), then, i think, one less case.

Comment: One option might be to use Janino to generate Java code and dodge the scala question altogether until there is a more stable solution.